# XML to PHP parsing.

Tags: php, xml

I tried to search the web for any good samples but I don´t get them to work with my xml feed.

I´m parsing this file https://www.kursadmin.org/pls/kas/sf_fu.create_web_cdata_xml
but it will only return the first field.

The feed is a list of courses and I would like to parse out a list of all cours titles and IDs.

This is what I got so far but it only parse out the first course (KURS).

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("https://www.kursadmin.org/pls/kas/sf_fu.create_web_cdata_xml");

foreach($xml as $x) {
 echo $x->KURS->KURS_NAVN . "<br><br>";
}
```

Any great suggestions - all new to this kind of parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add one more `foreach` to loop and traverse for all `KURS` object

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("https://www.kursadmin.org/pls/kas/sf_fu.create_web_cdata_xml");

foreach($xml as $x) {
    foreach($x->KURS as $y){
        echo $y->KURS_NAVN . "<br><br>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thaks! :) As simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

You fell into the trap of SimpleXMLs automatic mapping. You iterate the child elements of the document element. This is the `ReportArea` inside the `Report` element node. You iterate this single element and access the first KURS and the first KUR_NAVN element inside it.

Use DOM+Xpath to fetch data from an XML. This is more like using SQL for an database.

```
// create the DOM and load the XML
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('https://www.kursadmin.org/pls/kas/sf_fu.create_web_cdata_xml');

// create an Xpath object an register a prefix for the namespace
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$xpath->registerNamespace('cr', 'urn:crystal-reports:schemas');

// fetch the KURS_NAVN nodes and output them
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//cr:KURS/cr:KURS_NAVN') as $node) {
  echo $node->nodeValue . "<br>\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Spesialpedagogisk assistent- Mosjøen<br>
Spanskkurs nybegynner del 1+2 (A1), intensiv - Oslo<br>
Datakurs: Data grunnkurs - nybegynnere<br>
Norsk litt øvet (A2) - Eid<br>
Norskkurs mellomnivå del B (B1) - Bergen (1231)<br>
Sykurs: For det meste - helg<br>
Franskkurs nybegynner del 2, A1 - Biri<br>
...
```

Or, you can iterate the KURS element nodes and use them as an context for additional expressions.

```
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//cr:KURS') as $node) {
  echo $xpath->evaluate('string(cr:KURS_NAVN)', $node) . "<br>\n";
}
```