# Parse XML with PHP where Value equals XX

Tags: php, xml

Want to set up a page that parse out info from a XML feed according to a give ID...

Like "Show the Course->info where Course->ID = 123"

Probably "need" to get the id from a URL Variable ... urL: ://.../courseinfo.php?id=123

This show each instance - but I want a solution that shows only info from One particual ID.
"simialr" to a sql query like "GET * where COURSE_ID=" & $urlcourseid"

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("https://www.kursadmin.org/pls/kas/sf_fu.create_web_cdata_xml");

foreach($xml as $x) {
    foreach($x->KURS as $y){
        echo "Kursnavn: " . $y->KURS_NAVN . "<br>";
        echo "KursID: " . $y->KURS_ID . "<br><br>";
        echo "Formål: " . $y->FORMAL . "<br>";
        //echo "Beskrivelse: <p>" . $y->INNHOLD . "</p>";
        echo "<br><br> <Hr>";
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should use [xpath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) to query the xml for the needed value. Such value can be fetched via `$_GET` parameter, but remember to sanitise it before!

Comment: I already explained the basics for that in an answer to your last question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24036000/2265374 - The syntax for conditions in Xpath is [condition]. Example: `//cr:KURS[cr:KURS_ID = 1453388656]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As everyone's probably suggested, you should be using XPath to query this. What they're leaving out is that you have to mind the XML namespace before you can do that here.  Here's a programmatic way to both mind the namespace, and to query for a specific record ID:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file( "sf_fu.create_web_cdata_xml" );
$namespaces = $xml->getNamespaces( true );  # array([]="crystal-reports:schemas")
$namespace = array_shift( $namespaces );    # urn:crystal-reports:schemas
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("kurses", $namespace );
$results = $xml->xpath( "//kurses:KURS[kurses:KURS_ID=1463486771]" );
```

Note that my XPath query is prefixed with `kurses:` - that is the namespace prefix that I designated I wanted to use with the queries, that the XML file reflects (see the `Report xmlns=''` tag)

Anyhow, the result is an array of records, in our case length 1 since there's only one ID with that number. Printing it out looks like what you'd expect (redacted a few details):

```
print_r($results) = Array (
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
        [@attributes] => Array (
                [SectionNumber] => 0
                [teller] => 0
            )
        [KURSSERIE_ID] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
                [@attributes] => Array (
                        [FieldName] => {ARRMENT_TBL.AM_ID}
                    )
            )
        [KURS_ID] => 1463486771
        [KURS_NAVN] => Norsk litt øvet (A2) - Eid
        [KLSTART] => 1730
```

Given that the record ID # is an integer, you should be able to cheaply sanitize it by doing something like:

```
$KURS_ID = intval( $_GET['KURS_ID'] );
...
$results = $xml->xpath( "//kurses:KURS[kurses:KURS_ID={$KURS_ID}]" );
```

Comment: I did not leave the namespace out and you should not read the namespace from the XML file. The namespace define the semantics of the elements in an XML file. Reading the namespace from the XML is  like ignoring it.

Comment: Ok @pp19dd & @ThW! Thanks.
But I´m not really to familiar with arrays.

I´m using the values in this and it will be parsed out as a part of a template.

i.e I want to use the KURS_NAVN (translated: course_name) as a page title and KURS_PRIS (course_price) in another part of the template.

How can i parse it to strings I then again can "input" where I want in the final template?

Answer (score 0):

the obvious way:

```
foreach($xml as $x) {
    foreach($x->KURS as $y){
        if( $y->KURS_ID == $_GET['id']){
                echo "Kursnavn: " . $y->KURS_NAVN . "<br>";
                echo "KursID: " . $y->KURS_ID . "<br><br>";
                echo "Formål: " . $y->FORMAL . "<br>";
                //echo "Beskrivelse: <p>" . $y->INNHOLD . "</p>";
                echo "<br><br> <Hr>";
        }
    }
}
```